# Pip Install mljar Mercury failing with codec decode issue

Tags: pip, mljar

pip install mljar-mercury is failing. Tried Python 3.7/3.8/3.9/3.10, few blogs suggested, still not luck. Ensured default encoding is UTF-8 on machine.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What operating system are you using? Windows? Have you tried with conda? Why are installing packages from notebook? Can you please try to install from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

There was an encoding error when reading `README.md` file in `setup.py` file. It was fixed in the [#81](https://github.com/mljar/mercury/issues/83). Please update the [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) package to the latest version (`0.6.9`):

```
pip install -U mljar-mercury==0.6.9
```

Thank you!